# I need a converter to make any jquery code to make no.conflict mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I need a converter to make any jquery code/plugin to make with no.conflict mode?

or it's just possible with find and replace.

Comment: To make what with no conflict mode? Do you mean making 3rd party Jquery plugins etc. work with No Conflict Mode?

Comment: yes i works with jquery along with other libraries most og the time. so whenever i use any jquery plugin or snippet i covert those in no conflict mode

Comment: i just want to save time in this process

Answer (score 1):

As for the `$` shortcut: if you place the code e.g. in a properly crafted anonymous function, you can still use it. Like:

```
    (function ($, undefined) {

        //Use $ shortcut for jQuery in this scope
        $("input").val("clickme");

    })(jQuery.noConflict());
```

The same works for the "extreme" variant of `noConflict()`:

```
    (function (jQuery, undefined) {
        var $ = jQuery;

        //Use jQuery and $ shortcut for jQuery in this scope
        $("input").val("clickme");

    })(jQuery.noConflict(true));
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to manually do this. There are no converters out there to do this automatically. The jQuery [guide to authoring plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) specifically describes how plugins should bind to `jQuery` as opposed to the `$` specifically to ensure they remain working if `jQuery.noConflict()` is called.

Basically it comes down to wrapping your code like this:

```
(function($) {

    // jQuery can be used freely using 
    // the "$" within this code block

})(jQuery);
```

Keep in mind that this will remove any accidental (and some intentional) global variables from the global scope. To make variables global, assign them to the `window` object, like this:

```
(function($) {

    var myGlobalObj = "hello world";
    window.myGlobalObj = myGlobalObj;
    // Now "myGlobalObj" can be accessed globally

})(jQuery);
```